# Obtener conteo de valores agrupados en SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

¿Cuantos personas son las que cumplen el siguiente requisito? ser hombre de  30 años o mas  y mujeres de 25 o menos
todo los datos los tengo en una sola tabla pero al momento de hacer mi query

```
SELECT COUNT(sexo) as 'sexo',edad 
FROM empleado
GROUP BY sexo,edad 
HAVING sexo = 'H' and edad>30 or sexo = 'M' AND edad > 25;
```

me muestra esto

```
sexo     edad 
 1        29
 1        31
 3        32
 1        32
 1        35
 1        37 
 1        45
 1        50
 1        56
 1        58
```

Sólo necesito dos filas que digan hombre, mujer y edad

Comment: El problema está en que al tener diferentes edades el group by no los agrupa y es por eso que te sale mal sin mencionar que estas usando un having en vez de un where. A mi entender. tu consigna es que debes mostrar la cantidad de personas hombres > =30 años y mujeres <= 25 años.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunos puntos por mencionar:

- La otra consulta propuesta es correcta, solo que el operador entre las 2 condiciones del `WHERE` y las 2 últimas no puede ser `AND` ya que estarías indicando que los 2 juegos de condiciones se cumplan, lo cual en mas de una ocasión no será así
- Por otro lado, si vas a usar valores de columnas que ya existen en tu tabla para componer un filtrado como en este caso lo son el `sexo` y la `edad` entonces [lo correcto es usar `WHERE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- En cambio si por ejemplo desearas construir algún filtro por el valor de alguna columna calculada entonces [lo correcto es el uso de `HAVING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), ya que como puedes leer en la doc. esta pensado para:

  - Establecer una condición de búsqueda
  - Dicha condición estará dada para un grupo o para un agregado

**Ejemplo**

> Si quisieras de ese posible conjunto de resultados filtrar solo por aquellos cuyo conteo de personas que están dentro del rango de edades es mayor a 20, entonces nos valdría hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sexo = 'm' THEN 'masculino' ELSE 'femenino' END AS [Sexo Persona], 
COUNT(edad) AS Conteo
FROM empleado
WHERE sexo = 'm' and edad >= 30
OR 
sexo = 'f' AND edad <= 25
GROUP BY sexo
HAVING COUNT(edad) > 20;
```

Ya que si tratamos de aplicar un `WHERE` en lugar de `HAVING` para hacer el mismo filtrado obtendremos un error similar a este:

> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

(*Esto claramente tiene una teoría mas completa y extensa de por medio así que recomiendo leer a detalle el enlace propuesto*)

(No soy ningún experto de SQL Server, así que usé la clausula `CASE`para establecer un condicional y poder tener un texto mas amplio que solo *m* y *f*. )

Entonces tu consulta quedaría mas o menos así:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sexo = 'm' THEN 'masculino' ELSE 'femenino' END AS [Sexo Persona], 
COUNT(edad) AS Conteo
FROM empleado
WHERE sexo = 'm' and edad >= 30
OR 
sexo = 'f' AND edad <= 25
GROUP BY sexo;
```

Y montando un ejemplo, una posible vista de la salida de tus datos sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como extra.

- [Recomiendo leas sobre `agrupamiento`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

¿Cuantos personas son las que cumplen el siguiente requisito?
Ser hombre >= 30
Ser mujer <= 25

```
SELECT COUNT(sexo) AS Cantidad
...
WHERE sexo = 'H' AND edad >= 30 
  AND sexo = 'M' AND edad <= 25;
```